# strictly positive floats as its argument, Normalization

Tags: python

I am trying to compose a function that takes an array of strictly positive floats as its argument and rescales the array so that each element is between 0 & 1. However, I keep getting " '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int' " when attempting to accept only positive inputs.

This is where I am stuck on for the last 2 hours:

```
import stdio


def Normalize(a):
    norm = [(float(i)-min(a))/(max(a)-min(a)) for i in a]

    return norm


def main():
    a = list(map(float, input().split()))
    if a >=0 :
        Normalize(a)
        print(Normalize(a))
    else: 
        print("Inputs must be positive")

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Check the line: `if a[i]>=0` what is this `i` supposed to be there?

Comment: In "main" variable "i" **is** never defined (=set). What do you think should it be? By the way: If there is an error, always show the full traceback as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: How should a list be greater then 0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are trying to compare list and int in  `a >= 0`

Try replacing it with `all(i>=0 for i in a)`. Also, you may consider optimizing you normalization function, you don't need to search for `min` and `max` of array per every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to run your function, if there are at least 2 values input, hence your `if` statement should be:

```py
if len(a) > 1:
```

The error message says that `a >= 0` doesn't make sense.

If you want to make sure that all input values are positive, then use:

```py
if all([aa > 0 for aa in a]):
```